# Simple html and javascript files - Some part of the javaScript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I have no idea why my script isn't working. When I unchecked the boldface and italic checkbox, it is supposed to make the text "web design" normal. And also, the alignment and backgroundcolor javaScript aren't working at all. Appreciate if anyone can help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> <!-- Put your page title here -->  </title>

<style>
td{border:1px solid;}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<form action=""  method="get">

<table>

<tr>
<td width="300px"> <span id="textMessage">Web Design</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><span>Boldface</span></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="typeBold" value="boldFace" onclick="setBold();" /></td>
<td ></td>
<td><span>Italicized</span></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="type" id="typeItalic" value="italics" onclick="setItalic();" />
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span>Left</span></td>
<td><input type="radio" id="align" name="align" value="left" onclick="setAlign();"/></td>
<td></td>
<td>Center</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="align" name="align" value="center" onclick="setAlign();" /></td>
<td></td>
<td>Right</td> 
<td><input type="radio" id="align" name="align" value="right" onclick="setAlign();"/>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Red</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="color" name="color" value="red" onclick="setColor();"/></td>
<td></td>
<td>Blue</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="color" name="color" value="blue" onclick="setColor();" /></td>
<td></td>
<td>Green</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="color" name="color" value="green" onclick="setColor();"/>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td ><input type="submit" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>

<script>

function setBold(){

var type = document.getElementById("typeBold").value;

var text = document.getElementById("textMessage"); 

if(type!=null){

text.style.fontWeight = "bold";
return false;
} else{
text.style.fontWeight = "normal";
}
}

function setItalic(){

var type = document.getElementById("typeItalic").value;

var text = document.getElementById("textMessage"); 

if(type!=null){

text.style.fontStyle = "italic";
return false;
} else{
text.style.fontStyle = "normal";
}
}


function setAlign(){

var type = document.getElementById("align").value;

var text = document.getElementById("textMessage"); 

if(type=="left"){

text.style.textAlign = "left";
return false;
} 
else if (type=="center"){
text.style.textAlign = "center";
return false;
}
else{

text.style.textAlign = "right";
return false;
}
}


function setColor(){

var type = document.getElementById("color").value;

var text = document.getElementById("textMessage"); 

if(type=="green"){

text.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
return false;
} 
else if (type=="blue"){
text.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
return false;
}
else{

text.style.textAlign.backgroundColor = "tomato";
return false;
}
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ID` Should be unique. You have lot of bug in your snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `value` attribute of checkbox. You should be using `checked`.

Your `setBold` function should look like bellow

```
function setBold() {
    var isChecked = document.getElementById("typeBold").checked;
    var text = document.getElementById("textMessage");
    if (isChecked) {
        text.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    } else {
        text.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
```

You cannot have more than one element with same `id` better to change them as `alignLeft`, `alignCenter` & `alignRight`.

Comment: Thank you. Now, about the alignment, the thing is, I don't want to have 3 functions to each alignment type, I want only one, so I can check the value name to see which type of alignment is.

Comment: Finished everything. Thanks people!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text color use `text.style.color = "tomato"` instead.
For the alignment apply the change to the `<td>` tag